# Set Identities (Statistical Inference Ed. 2)

Tags: statistics, elementary-set-theory

I'm working ahead in *Statistical Inference* and I've gotten stuck on the second section of homework exercises for Chapter 1 - I believe I know how to set up the problem and work through it but I'd like another pair of eyes on it to confirm that I'm making the right progress. Also, I believe that the notation "A-B" for relative complement isn't standard, but I wasn't sure how to work around the equation not showing the "\" symbol when I placed it. Thanks in advance for the help!

The problem is as follows:

Verify the following identities:

1.2(a)

$$(A - B) = (A - (A \bigcap B)) = (A \bigcap B^c)$$

My work so far:

Show that $$(A - (A \bigcap B)) \subset (A - B)$$
Let $$x \in (A - (A \bigcap B)) $$ This means that $$x \in A $$ and $$x \notin (A \bigcap B)$$

From here I'm not sure where to proceed to equate that as a subset of (A-B).

Comment: Go for a contradiction? Suppose $x \notin A - B$ so that $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ which contradicts $x \notin A \cap B$

Comment: $X-Y$ means "in $X$ **and** not in $Y$".  The "and" is an intersection.  So $X-Y$ is "in $X$" $\cap$ "not in $Y$", which is basically by definition $X\cap Y^c$. Now let $X=A$ and $Y=A\cap B$ and see where you can get.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $\setminus$ is created using `$\setminus$`.

You want to show that your $x$ is in $A-B$, or in other words, that it is in $A$ but not $B$. You've already shown it is in $A$. To see it is not in $B$, suppose for sake of contradiction that it is in $B$; then $x \in A \cap B$, which contradicts your assertion that $x \notin A \cap B$.

The other inclusion is easy, since "subtracting $B$" takes away more than "subtracting $A \cap B$."

Equating $A \cap B^c$ to the other two is a matter of reading the definition of $A-B$, as Steve D pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x\in A\backslash B$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$. That is, $x\in A$, and $x\notin (A\cap B)$. Hence $x\in (A\backslash(A\cap B))$.

Additionally, if $x\notin B$, then $x\in B^C$ (by definition of the complement). Since $x\in A$ and $x\in B^C$, $x\in (A\cap B^C)$.

Therefore $A\backslash B \subseteq (A\backslash(A\cap B))$ and $A\backslash B \subseteq (A\cap B^C )$

Now let $x\in (A\backslash(A\cap B))$. Then $x\in A$, and $x\notin (A\cap B)$. As we know $x\in A$, $x\notin (A\cap B)$ implies $x\notin B$. That is, $x\in A\backslash B$.

Furthermore, because $x\notin B$, we have $x\in B^C$. Thus $x\in A\cap B^C$.

Therefore $(A\backslash(A\cap B)) \subseteq A\backslash B$ (proving the first equality) and $(A\backslash(A\cap B)) \subseteq A\backslash B$.

Now suppose $x\in (A\cap B^C)$. Then $x\in A$, and $x\in B^C$. Because $B\cap B^C = \emptyset$, if $x\in B^C$, then $x\notin B$. So $x\in A\backslash B$, and (as shown above), this implies $x\in (A-(A\cap B))$. Then $(A\cap B^C) \subseteq A\backslash B$ and $A\cap B^C \subseteq A\backslash (A\cap B)$, proving the last equality (and the implied transitive one).

It might also help to draw a venn diagram.